# docker desktop tutorial: Unable to find image 'alpine/git:latest' locally, failed

Tags: docker

Just installed docker desktop for windows, following the tutorial, but the first command failed:

```
C:\docker>docker run --name repo alpine/git clone https://github.com/docker/getting-started.git
Unable to find image 'alpine/git:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers).
See 'docker run --help'.
```

Comment: You're getting a client timeout trying to interact with Docker. Either it's a transient problem and it will go away on its own, or there is something in your network that is blocking access to `https://registry-1.docker.io`. Neither situation is really something for which we can provide assistance.

Comment: Tried to open "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/" from browser,  got  {"errors":[{"code":"UNAUTHORIZED","message":"authentication required","detail":null}]}